# 400 Bad request when passing in variables in gql (Apollo client)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I'm trying to pass some variables into my gql string but can't seem to get it to work. When passing in the data manually the query works.

```
  const UPDATE_WEATHER = gql`
  {
    weatherByLocation(
      latitude: "51.8917473"
      longitude: "-2.0877334999999997"
    ) {
      currently {
        summary
      }
    }
  }
`;

const WeatherInfo = ({ lat, long }) => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(UPDATE_WEATHER, {
    variables: { lat, long },
  });

  if (loading) return null;
  if (error) return `Error! ${error}`;

  return <h1>{data.weatherByLocation[0].currently.summary}</h1>;
};
```

I've tried following the guide [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#caching-query-results) but with no success. Here is my updated gql with the variables

```
const UPDATE_WEATHER = gql`
  query weatherByLocation($lat: String!, $long: String!) {
    weatherByLocation(latitude: $lat, longitude: $long) {
      currently {
        summary
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

However this results in a 400 bad request. Here is the request payload

```
operationName: "weatherByLocation"
query: "query weatherByLocation($lat: String!, $long: String!) {↵  weatherByLocation(latitude: $lat, longitude: $long) {↵    currently {↵      summary↵      __typename↵    }↵    __typename↵  }↵}↵"
variables: {lat: 51.891751299999996, long: -2.0877779}
```

Comment: striiiiiiiiiiings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your variables into String! Because in the Query you expect variables with the type of string